# Pandas Slicing Values Where All Values in Columns are Equal

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, slice

Imagine I had a dataframe with 3 columns like the example below.  I'm looking for a Pandaic/Pythonic way to take a slice of a dataframe where all three columns column have the same value. In this case, I'd like the resultant to be a dataframe with only row 0 and row 3.  Does anyone have a great method other than brute force?

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : [1, 2, 3, 'foo'], 
                  'Col2' : [1, 4, 5, 'foo'],
                  'Col3' : [1, 12, 13, 'foo']})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `nunique`

```
df1[df1.nunique(1)==1]
Out[171]: 
  Col1 Col2 Col3
0    1    1    1
3  foo  foo  foo
```

Comment: To make it clear `df1[df1.nunique(axis=1)==1]`.  Axis 1 meaning "across the columns".  So the code says, get all the rows whose number of unique values is 1 across the columns.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation and solution.  I was not thinking enough outside the box.